# ASIHTTPRequest debugging

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest in my iOS project. i would like to see all the http headers of my request to the server. How I can see this with ASIHTTPRequest?

Is there any tool like fiddler in the mac?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `requestHeaders` property. It is `NSMutableDictionary`, so you can iterate through it. Dictionary key is name of header and dictionary value for this key is value of header with this name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i would like to add an http header to may request (ASIHTTPRequest), for example the Accept header, can i do this from the code ?

Comment: Surely! `[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];`, for example

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the following macro below which is found in ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h, I've used this to help with debugging HTTP headers.

```
#define DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just print them out:

```
// headers in server response 
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"headers: %@", [request responseHeaders]);
}
```

And to see the headers of your request:

```
     NSLog(@"headers: %@", [request requestHeaders]);
```

Comment: Thanks. NSLog(@"headers: %@", [request requestHeaders]); show to me (null), is this correct with my request. ( my request to my wer service is working fine, but [request requestHeaders] show to me (null) in the console)